# Getting a field from the first row of a query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter's Active Record Class. So the query looks something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('Table', array('field' => $value));
```

Now, what's the fastest way to get a field from the first row?
Would `$query->first_row->field`; work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though fast is wonderful, errors aren't! Make sure you always check for results before trying to access them with `($query->num_rows() > 0)`

**Fastest (most concise) way:**

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('Table', array('field' => $value));

echo(($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->first_row()->field : 'No Results');
```

**Essentially the same as:**

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('Table', array('field' => $value));
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    echo $query->first_row()->field;
}
else
{
    echo 'No Results';
}
```

**For multiple fields use:**

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('Table', array('field' => $value));

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $row = $query->row(); 

    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$query->first_row()->field
```